# Modeling relative percentage figures

Tags: modeling, percentage

I have data which reports the relative performance (in percentage) of several candidate objects with respect to a standard object. In other words, the performance of the standard object is always reported as 100%, while that of the candidate objects could be below or above 100% , i.e. the performance could be 200% ,it could also be 10% but never negative. Apart from the dependent variable , i.e., the relative performance %, there are several other independent variables (continuous and discrete) none of which are percentages or relative percentages.

Which statistical modelling techniques are best suited to model the relative performance of the candidate objects?

I have gone through some other questions related to modelling percentages via linear regression or by using logit transformation or using logistic regression or beta regression. I could transform my data by subtracting 100 from the relative performance % to arrive at a new transformed independent variable with values between (+$\infty$, -$\infty$) and then use multiple linear regression perhaps? Are there any other methods which I could try?

Comment: What could bite is whether the outcome could be zero. If not, then things are simpler, but it's hard to know whether taking the outcome as reported or working with its logarithm would be better. I can't see any special need for or value from first ubtracting 100 either way. and in any case your values are not going to cover the whole line; they are still bounded below by $-100$, whether inclusively or not.